# Compare two values from one column based on values in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have table where I need to compare two values based on their names in another column to see which one is bigger. Basically:

```
If **name1** -> value1
If **name2** -> value2
Compare **value1 > value2**
```

[image]

I have done summations but I cannot find a way to use the `CASE WHEN` approach to this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `PIVOT` the data and have all values in current row. Then, compare them as you like:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[name1], [name2], [name3], [name4]
FROM [my_table]
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [column] IN ([name1], [name2], [name3], [name4])
) PVT
```

or

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN [column] = 'name1' THEN [value] END) AS [name1]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN [column] = 'name2' THEN [value] END) AS [name2]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN [column] = 'name3' THEN [value] END) AS [name3]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN [column] = 'name4' THEN [value] END) AS [name4]
FROM [my_table]
GROUP [Id];
```

Comment: Well, you never mention the amount of data? I can give you another techniques but you need to share more details.

Comment: the column name comes from another ID table and is growing. Currently it has around 20  different names, which are names of different indicators. I found a little workaround and added a WHERE clause to your solution to filter the names that I want.

Comment: @Yana You can try the second technique, too. The best approach will be to pre-calculated the values in `PIVOT` manner in new table as there will be no need to perform this operation live.